# SharePoint Designer initiation form parameter People or group

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I want to create a SPD 2013 workflow with people or group initiation form parameter. Problem is that this option is not present. If I activate "Workflows" site collection feature, option is available. As 2010 workflows will be disabled, does this site collection feature will be impacted ? And 2013 workflows using people or group initiation form parameter will not work anymore ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no official documents stating that the "Workflows" site collection feature will be deprecated.

So you could use initiation form parameter for person or group in SharePoint 2013 workflow.

However, we recommend customers move to Power Automate or other supported solutions, such as those from Preferred members of our Microsoft 365 Business Apps Partner Program.